# How do you cycle between weapons of the same type and insult or compliment people in GTA 5 on PC?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

On the Xbox 360 (and presumably the other consoles) version of the game you were able to walk up to people and press left and right on the dpad to either insult or compliment people, not really any use except it was a bit fun and a good way to start fights.

I can't for the life of me work out what the button is on PC for this. I'd have thought it was left and right arrow keys but this doesn't seem to be the case and I can't find a button for it in configuration.

Also, if I have more than one weapon in the weapon wheel slot (say if I have an Uzi and an MP5) I can't work out how to easily switch between the 2 minus by pressing the number key for that weapon slot repeatedly. Any ideas?

Comment: There's 'M' to bring up an interaction menu but since I'm at work, I can't confirm it does include what you're looking for. Isn't the scroll wheel on the mouse to switch weapon? That is the usual setting in most game, if Rockstar went another way, they made a mistake there.

Comment: The M interaction button is for fast GPS and whatnot, I thought that'd be it also. Scrollwheel cycles through the "wheel" of weapons, but its divided into segments, like pistols, smgs, assault rifles etc. If you have multiple pistols there's no easy way to scroll through them.

Comment: Bah, they should have just made it next and previous weapon on scroll...

Comment: You're asking two questions here, right? If yes, please remove one and ask it separately.

Answer (score 13):

You can switch between types of weapons by holding <kbd>Tab</kbd> and move the mouse to the desired weapon category on the weapon wheel, then scroll the mouse-wheel to cycle between the guns in that category.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This is not a conventional forum, where it is just a long conversation. There are questions, answers, and comments on both. Once you reach 50 reputation, you can create commentary on both of these. However, the answer section is only for answers.

Comment: Please excuse my confusion but I'd like some clarification.  I have included a description of how to cycle through the weapons as he had requested, does this not count as an answer? or does an answer have to address all aspects of the question?

Comment: @EliasBenevedes To me this sounds like an answer to the question. Can you please explain why do you think this should be a comment?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd have thought it was left and right arrow keys but this doesn't seem to be the case and I can't find a button for it in configuration.

Press <kbd>E</kbd> according to the Steam forums:

http://steamcommunity.com/app/271590/discussions/0/611703709829902688/

> Also, if I have more than 1 weapon in the weapon wheel slot (say if I have an Uzi and an MP5) I can't work out how to easily switch between the 2 minus by pressing the number key for that weapon slot repeatedly. Any ideas?

That is how you switch (as you say) by repeatedly pressing the slot number.

Comment: yes this is the answer. press the number keys to cycle weapons

Answer (score 0):

on foot you can switch between weapons while holding tab and scrolling mouse

Answer (score -1):

the way I did it was to use the number key of the weapon slot so hitting 7 on your numbers not on the numpad, multiple times will cycle the weapon slot

Comment: This seems to differ from what the accepted answer says. Do you have a source?